# how to list item in dropdown based on another dropdown using xml file?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, drop-down-menu

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" intent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <center>
                <select id='bookID' onchange='getInputs(this.value)'>
                    <xsl:for-each select="BookDetail/book" >
                        <option><xsl:value-of select="bookName"/></option>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </select>
                <select id="bookLink">
                        <xsl:for-each select="BookDetail">
                                    <option><xsl:value-of select="link"/>    </option>                                    
                            </xsl:for-each>
                </select>
                </center>                    
              </body>
        </html>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have created an XML file where the details of book is stored.

There are two dropdowns 1) BookName 2 )BookLink

Now I want is to change dropdown list of BookLink when any book name is selected from the dropdown.

XML File is as below:

```
<BookDetail>
     <book>
    <bookName>Dollar Bahu</bookName>
    <link>http:\\DollarBahu.in</link>
    </book>
    <book>
    <bookName>The Lost Symbol</bookName>
    <link>http:\\TheLostSymbol.in</link>
    </book>
    <book>
    <bookName>Keep The Change</bookName>
    <link>http:\\KeepTheChange.in</link>
    </book>
</BookDetail>
```

Comment: If someone knows how to get values from anothrr dropdown then please reply

Comment: @Mauker Can you answer my question?